# Use fetch with browser cookies

Tags: javascript, php, session, fetch

I have created a PHP page on my server which look like that

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['sellername'])) {
    echo "Ok";
} else {
    echo "No session found";
}
```

And from an other page (not on the same server) I have this function

```js
async function sessionCheck() {
  let res = await fetch("https://example.com/check_session.php");
  let msg = await res.text();
  return (msg == "Ok");
}
```

but it won't recognize that the session is active even if I am connected.

How can I fetch, but using the browser cookies (or whatever I need to be recognized by the server)?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch doesn't send cookies by default.

Add `credentials: 'include'` to the request options

```
await fetch("https://www.MYURL.com/check_session.php", { credentials: "include" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am now getting this error :
`Access to fetch at 'https://www.MYURL.com/check_session.php' from origin 'http://www.MYURL2.me' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

But if i remove the header from the php code i can't event fetch data from it

Comment: Thats a CORS issue. You should not remove the header, but instead replace the wildcard * with a list of domains that should be able to fetch data from the server.

Comment: @AACT2 If this was helpful, set this as answer :)